Confusion between Separable (degenerate) kernel and Convolution (difference) kernel
Let $k(x,t)$ denote kernel in Integral Equation.
Take $k(x,t)=e^{x-t}$. At first look, it seems convolution kernel. But It can be written as $e^{x}×e^{-t}$. Then, Is it separable kernel ?
Similarly, for $k(x,t)=sin(x-t)$, Is it convolution as well as separable kernel?
If anyone can help me with the justification, it will be of great help. Thanks in advance.
